# Vaadin can't change button color

Tags: java, css, eclipse, vaadin

I tried changing the color of my buttons in the `style.css` and in the `mytheme.scss` file, but when I change the background colour in `.mytheme .v-button` nothing happens. I'm using the Valo theme. Am I doing something wrong?

This is the code from `Style.css`

```
.mytheme .v-button {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 37px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    color: #191919;
    font-weight: 400;


    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
    border-top-color: #c5c5c5;
    border-bottom-color: #bcbcbc;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa 2%, #efefef 98%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fafafa 2%, #efefef 98%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 white, inset 0 -1px 0 #e7e7e7, 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 white, inset 0 -1px 0 #e7e7e7, 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
```

EDIT:

I now have the problem that my vertical layout wont center:

```
public MainMenuView() {
    vLayout.addComponent(buttons);
    vLayout.setSizeFull();
    vLayout.setComponentAlignment(buttons, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    this.setCompositionRoot(vLayout);

    addMerchant.setStyleName("mystyle");
    showMerchants.setStyleName("mystyle");
    merchantSearch.setStyleName("mystyle");
    lHeader.addStyleName("mylabelstyle");
    addMerchant.addClickListener(e -> addMerchant());
    showMerchants.addClickListener(e -> showMerchants());
    merchantSearch.addClickListener(e -> merchantSearch());

}
```

Comment: You have background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fafafa 2%, #efefef 98%); and background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fafafa 2%, #efefef 98%); still set. These are effectively producing the background of the button, so the color definition #000000 i.e. black is only a fallback option.

Comment: @TatuLund yes I noticed this as well but now even after compiling I have the problem that it for some reason takes forever to show the changes I made, for example I changed the color 10 mins ago but in chrome it still shows the old color and in eclipse it never shows  button colors for some reason even though chrome does :/

Comment: Note 1: You need to use shift + refresh with browser to force reloading styles.css, by default browser uses version from the cache and hence you do not see changes. Note 2: You should not edit styles.css, just edit theme scss files and compile theme.

Comment: @TatuLund thanks it works now :) I cant center my VerticalLayout for some reason though. vLayout.setComponentAlignment(buttons, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER); only shifts it slightly to the right for some reason. I'll edit my Question with the full code.